# How to concatenate two LPCWSTR's in c++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, concatenation

I'm trying to use the MoveFile(LPCWSTR existing, LPCWSTR new) function. I'd like to be able the one of the directories (represented by LPCWSTR) by concatenating different data (for example: root directories and potential file names). Despite hours of research, I can't figure out how to do this. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to combine two `LPCWSTR` which represent paths elements into a combined paths.  If that's the case then you want to use the [PathCombine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773571%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method

```
LPCWSTR root = ...;
LPCWSTR name = ...;
WCHAR combined[MAX_PATH];
if (PathCombineW(combined, root, name) != NULL) {
  // Succeeded
}
```

Comment: Minor nit, but when you're actually dealing with `WCHAR`s, shouldn't you use `PathCombineW`? Not that non-Unicode Windows is used much, but people do still build applications in non-Unicode mode.

Comment: I had to initialize the variable before using it: `WCHAR combined[MAX_PATH] = L"";`

Comment: Note: the documentation now says that this can potentially lead to buffer overflow and that you should use PathCchCombine instead. Additionally this is only available for windows 8 and up and windows server 2012

Answer (score 0):

You should use [**`_wmakepath_s()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5a1745t0.aspx) for composing a wide-char path.